# Android Studio Java Thread causes lag

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I have a big list of objects that I need to update. I tried to make a thread to improve the performance, but in exchange I earn HUGE lag, so much lag it crashes my app from not responding.

```
playerR = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (j = 0; j < platforms.length; j++)
            for (i = 0; i < blocks.get(j).size(); i++) {
                block = blocks.get(j).get(i);
                block.update(playerClass.posX, playerClass.posY, playerClass.immune, playerClass.sizeX, errorLeft, errorRight, 0);
                block.update(dumbAi.posX, dumbAi.posY, dumbAi.immune, dumbAi.sizeX, errorLeft, errorRight,1);

                block.draw(cameraX, cameraY, spriteBatch);
            }
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

    }
};
playerThread = new Thread(playerR);
playerThread.start();
```

This code is in render() function in main class. Any suggestions? I am kind of new to threads.

Comment: It is possible your phone does not have multiple cores and is simply not powerful enough. Does it crash on your phone or in your emulator? Also, using threads to render things can get weird, generally doing all your processing then rendering everything separately works better than doing both simultaneously. Its also possible this is a deadlock, though there isnt enough code to tell. Check you logic.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer to your question but the code is pretty broken.  It looks to me as if access to 'platform' and 'block' are not correctly synchronized.  ... and the 'synchronized' block is not doing anything at all.  Finally, if 'block.draw' actually tries to draw anything, you will get an error for attempting to mutate UI objects from a worker thread.

Comment: I don't draw anything, I am not that noob. But I am noob enough to don't know what synchronized does, so how should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

use the `debugger` to find exactly where your execution is hanging in the code. and why the synchronized part is empty?